# Replace all references to a class with references to its interface

Tags: java, eclipse

I am refactoring some code. I have created some interfaces out of old classes (one to one). Now I would need to go through all the code replacing all the references to the class with a reference to the interface. In other words, replacing all the `MyObject` occurences with the `MyObjectIF` that I have just created.

Is there any easy way to do this in Eclipse?

Tks,
Daniel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right-click on the implementation class and select **Refactor** > **User Supertype Where Possible...**. In the resulting dialog select the interface as the supertype to use, then Preview to see all the places that will change.